# Integrate Rails and Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, pygame, integrate, panda3d

This might sound like a vague question, but i wanted to know if there is to integrate Python code into my rails application. More specifically, if i had a game coded with something like pygame (and it might be pushing too far to say panda3d), how could i make it so someone could play through their browser on my rails app (if you don't have a one paragraph answer, but a link to reading material that's fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panda3D applications can be run in the browser provided the user has a Panda3D plugin.  See section III of the Panda3D manual [Distributing Panda3D Applications](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Main_Page).

pygame cannot be run in the browser and thus cannot be integrated into a rails application.

I do not have rails experience, but I would be surprised if rails did not let you munge about with the html if needed.

Comment: thanks, i needed to know this before i even got started with using panda3d